# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx \, e^{i x t a} f(x) f(x-t b)$, where $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$, with $t$, $a$, $b$ real

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am trying to compute

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx \, e^{i x t a} f(x) f(x-t b)$$

where $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ and  $t, a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Mathematica for instance doesn't know how to do it. I have tried to do it in the complex plane. I think the contour should be something like in the picture, with two branch cuts: from $i$ to $-i$ and from $i+tb$ to $-i+tb$ (I forgot the $t$ in the figure).

[image: contour]

But the problem is that I don't know how to compute the integral along the vertical segments, next to the branch cuts, basically because it looks very similar to the actual integral. Any idea? Being able to compute the Fourier transform of the integral with respect to $t$ would also work for me.

Comment: It would be much easier to use Fourier transform properties since $$\mathcal{F}\left\{f(x)f(x-b)\right\} = (\hat{f} \star e^{iba}\hat{f})(a)$$ assuming a $-$ convention in the exponential

Comment: @NinadMunshi while true, the resulting function is a Bessel function, so OP will to deal with the convolution of two Bessel functions which is in general a very difficult computation. Most integrals of products of Bessel functions are centered around zero.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes, but I think you mean that my integral is $\big( f(x) \star e^{ia(b-x)} f(x) \big) (b)$. If you take the Fourier transform of my integral wrt $b$ then it simplifies, because the convolution becomes a product of Fourier transforms. But I don't want to work with the Fourier transform of my integral wrt $b$.

Comment: Are you sure that these four integrals have a closed form. And if yes - do youl already know the solution?

Comment: It is $=2\int_i^{i+b} e^{iax} (1+x^2)^{-1/2}(1+(x-b)^2)^{-1/2}dx$. I don't see why there should be a simpler expression.